# Задержка цикла

Tags: jquery, циклы

Наткнулся вот на что. Есть у меня объекты и  я по циклу гоняю запрос на сервер:

```
var obj=$("table tr");
obj.each(function(){
   $.post("index.php",{$(this).attr("id")},function(data){
       alert(data);
   });
});
```

Как добиться того, чтобы цикл делал задержку пока не получил ответ от сервера? То есть чтобы следующий шаг цикла совершался при получении ответа от сервера.

**UPD.**

Рекурсия?

Или как в таком случае поведет себя $.map()?

**UPD2**

```
var objs=$("table tr"); // length = 45
var i=0;
function reload_all(obj){
   if($(obj).attr("id")==undefined)return true;
   $(".reload_all_field").append($(obj).attr("id")+"|"+i+" ");
   i++;
   reload_all($(obj).next());
}
reload_all(objs);
// после обхода i = 38 вместо 44
```

Сделал таким образом, но из 45 объектов обрабатывается только 40. 5 штук пропускает после 5-го. В чем проблема-то? Может я .next() использую не по назначению?:(

Comment: Сделайте таймер на цикл. А время - сколько нужно вам.

Comment: По таймеру не подходит, нужно строго по получении ответа от сервера.

Comment: Интересно, сейчас попробую реализовать.

Comment: прочитал тему - сполз под стол =) думал форумом ошиблись =)

Comment: @Gorets, что?

Comment: вообще-то есть success, который срабатывает при ответе сервера

Comment: действительно, чем success не устраивает?

Comment: success может быть, но так получится рекурсия, что желательнее избегать, но думаю решение в ней.

Comment: Плохая формулировка вопроса, из того что вы написали - вам действительно нужен обычный `success`, если хотите получить вразумительный ответ - уточните вопрос

Comment: Приведенный мной код быстро пробегается по всем tr таблицы и ставит в очередь пост запросы на сервер (они конечно все выполняются), но цыкл заканчивается раньше чем получит ответ от первого запроса, а мне нужно, чтобы след шаг цыкла прошла после как получит ответ от сервера на текушем шаге.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Всё правильно вам написали выше. Кидаете код в функцию и по success рекурсия. А можно и **deferred** использовать, но смысл примерно тот же. 
[Посмотрите пример](http://jsfiddle.net/Deonis/sbHzF/1/)

Comment: Ну незнаю... Рабочий, конечно, вариант. но я думаю функция не найдет объект this. Сейчас проверим.

Comment: this - это не глобальная переменная, если что... Чтоб не возникло проблем, сделайте **var someName = $(this);** и работайте дальше с переменной **someName** без всяких проблем

Comment: Я написал что происходит с рекурсией...

Comment: Ну вот еще [демка](http://jsfiddle.net/sbHzF/14/), в примере @Deonis 'а, как и в моем - такого не происходит, соответственно косяк в коде.

Comment: @AlexWindHope я применил вашу функцию. Заработало. Спасибо. С примером @Deonis'а почему-то не сработало, пропускало как я говорил 5 штук, даже если объектов 1000.

Answer (score 0):

**Как-то так:**

```
var obj = $('table tr'), 
    q = $.when();
obj.each(function () {
 q = $.when(q, $.post('index.php', {
   $(this).attr("id")
 }));
});
d.done(function(){
  alert(true);
});
```

Не проверял, сам так никогда не делал, работоспособность **не гарантирую**.